# I am working with Android Data Binding from activity to layout as a string but its not showing

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am sending the string from my activity to the layout that is created as a common layout with data binding but it's not working. I have checked a lot of answers but nothing is working for me.

I want the same thing as the OP wants in following question, but the solution he accepted is not working for me.

[Passing string to included layout via data binding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452306/passing-string-to-included-layout-via-data-binding-not-working)

following is my layout resume_detail_heading.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="sectionTitle"
            type="java.lang.String" />
    </data>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/app_color_1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resume_detail_section_heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
            android:text="@{sectionTitle}"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

And This is my Activity where I am calling the layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    >

    <data>

        <variable
            name="sectionTitle"
            type="java.lang.String" />
    </data>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/availablitycardview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@color/color_white">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/availablity"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:text="Available Now"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/titleRole"
                layout="@layout/resume_detail_heading"
                app:sectionTitle="@{@string/app_name}" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp">

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/roles_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:scrollbars="none"></ListView>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                <!--For Skill-->
                <include
                    android:id="@+id/titleSkill"
                    layout="@layout/resume_detail_heading"
                    app:sectionTitle="@{`Skill`}" />
    ...............
```

Comment: define "sectionTitle" in activity layout also where you use "<include". i mean you have to define that "sectionTitle" variable in both layout

Comment: @android you mean that I neend to add 

<data>

        <variable
            name="sectionTitle"
            type="String" />
    </data>

into my activity? where I am using <include ....

Comment: yes in your activity layout also. you have to define "sectionTitle" variable in both layout

Comment: Not working for me I have used it in my activity :'(

Comment: use type="java.lang.String" instead of only type="String" and also don't use harcoded string like "app:sectionTitle="@{`Role`}" instead declare that in strings.xml and try to use it

Comment: I using type="java.lang.String" in both but layouts but the still same problem no error no success

Comment: please try not to use hard coded strings instead declare it in strings.xml and then try to check

Comment: now I am using this 
 app:sectionTitle="@{@string/app_name}" />
and stil same behaviour

Comment: upvoting your question. may be others can help you

Comment: Could you post how you're setting the activity's content view as well as the place where you set the binding variable from the activity pls?